# How to open a Win32 FILE* from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, msvcrt

I am trying to use the Win32 `msvcrt.dll` to open the standard output and print out some arbitrary string. Keep in mind that I do *not* want to use `print` or the `msvcrt` and `os` libraries.

I tried using `_fdopen` and `_fputs` but I consistently get an `OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000036B5FAA8`. I think the issue is that I can't have a `FILE*` in python and it gets converted to an `int` through `ctypes` but I cannot figure out how to convert that memory address (int) into an actual pointer to pass to the function. It's possible that I'm wrong and something else I'm doing is bad.

Code:

```py
c = __import__('ctypes.util')
c_lib = c.CDLL(c.util.find_library('msvcrt'))

fptr = c_lib._get_osfhandle(
  c.cast(
    1,
    c.POINTER(c.c_int),
  )
)

realf = c_lib._open_osfhandle(
  fptr,
  c.cast(
    8,
    c.POINTER(c.c_int),
  )
)

fd = c_lib._fdopen(realf,
  c.cast(
    b'w',
    c.POINTER(c.c_char),
  )
)

c_lib.fputs(
 c.cast(
    b'Hello msvcrt!',
    c.POINTER(c.c_char),
  ),
    fd
)

c_lib._flushall()
c_lib._close(realf)

c_lib._exit(
  c.cast(
    0,
    c.POINTER(c.c_int)
  )
)
```

Here's what I'm trying to do, but using `msvcrt` and `os`. It works perfectly:

```py
import msvcrt, os

fptr = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(1)
realf = msvcrt.open_osfhandle(fptr, os.O_APPEND)
fd = os.fdopen(realf, 'w')

fd.write('hello')
fd.flush()

os.close(realf)
```

How can I do the same thing but in the format of the previous code? I tried looking through the CPython source code to see what `os.fdopen` is doing internally but it is impossible to find anything there (so much nesting and github has poor search support). The code works identically up until the `fd` is opened. However, `os.fdopen` returns an `IO.TextIOWrapper` whilst `fd` results in some huge number (hex `36B5FAA8` but changes slightly each run due to memory allocation differences)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to specifically specify the return type of `_fdopen` to be a `ctypes.c_void_p` (pointer with an unspecified type) which worked successfully.

```py
# Specify the return type
c_lib._fdopen.restype = c.c_voidp
fd = c_lib._fdopen(realf,
  c.cast(
    b'w',
    c.POINTER(c.c_char),
  )
)
```

It appears that Python was trying to guess the return type (and assumed it wasn't a pointer), it would guess wrong and give a wrong result, which would then cause the `_fdopen` function to attempt to write to the incorrect spot causing an out-of-bounds write.